# Check for related file names and delete one of them

Tags: linux, shell, find, echo

I need to write a script that will find files that contain a string in their name.  If a file exists that is the same name but without that string, I want to remove the original file.

For example, if I am in a directory with the following files:

```
algomb
gomba
alb
algomba
alba
```

If the substring is `gom` then I would consider `algomb`, `gomba`, and `algomba`.  Removing `gom` from each of those names I would check for the existance of `alb`, `ba`, and `alba`.  Of those, `alb` and `alba` do exist, so I would remove `algomb` and `algomba` leaving just

```
alb
alba
gomba
```

in the directory when I'm done.

Here is what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
sz="gom"

talal=`find . -type f -name "*$sz*" -exec basename {} \;`
ossz=`find . -type f -exec basename {} \;`
c=`echo ${talal%%:*}${talal##*:}`

for c in ossz; do       
    if [ ! -d ]; then
        echo "This is a directory"  
    else    
        if [ -f ];
        then
            find .-type f -name "*$sz*" -exec basename {} \;  
        else
            echo ${talal%%:*}${talal##*:} 
        fi  
    fi
done
```

So this is works. This `echo ${talal%%:*}${talal##*:}` is give back the filename without "gom". But I can't compare these values with f`ind . -type f -exec basename {} \;` results.

Given that I can find the substrings, how can I test for the files and remove the appropriate ones?

Comment: What is the output when you execute the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you're asking:

```
#!/bin/bash
sz="gom"
dir="/where/the/files/are"

find $dir -type f -name "*${sz}*" -print0 | while read -d '' -r c; do
    if [[ -f "$(echo $c | sed 's/'"${sz}"'//g')" ]]; then
        # Strip the 'echo' to have this actually do things
        echo rm -v "$c"
    fi
done
```

Some notes on the changes and fixes:

- Find's `-printf "%f\n"` is preferable to `-exec basename {} \;`. In this case I've removed find stripping the dirname so that the script is safe for non-flat directory structures.
- `for c in ossz` shouldn't have ever worked - the barename `ossz` isn't a variable. `$ossz` would've been needed.
- Using `sed` is probably preferable to relying upon bash pattern matching and substitution for readability reasons.

Example:

For a directory containing the following files:

```
alb  alba  algomb  algomba  gomb
```

The script from above will output the following:

```
rm -v ./algomb
rm -v ./algomba
```

Comment: So if I understand right then this script "cut" the  $sz variable from all file name and the remaining will be compare with all files and if exist, then delete the file with $sz variable?

For example: there are 3 files:  algomba, alba, aladar,

I need a script what do the following:

1. Find all files with "gom".
2. "Cut" gom from filename, and compare other files:  in my example there are 1 file: algomba -> alba
3. If there is a file with this name, then delete the file, what contained "gom" : there is algomba -> cit "gom" -> alba  -> alba is exist, then remove algomba.

Sorry for my english

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I've added a demonstration of this to my answer. Note that you'll need to set the `dir` variable to whatever directory you want this to act on.

Comment: Hi, 

I set the dir variable: /home/oracle/work.  I delete the "echo" , then run the .sh file, but nothing happen.
What did I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my script. I was still doing a `basename` check in one place. Try with what I've updated. Be sure to use the `echo` method first to ensure it won't do anything you don't expect.

Comment: thanks.
Its almost good. I ran the script, and it tried to delete only one file. Before I ran the script  I made 3 other directories, 2 files in each of them. So there were 6 files that the script should delete. The part of the script `echo rm -v "$c"` I put it into a log file. There was only on row inserted there. Unfortunately I need to insert 6 rows. Do you have any idea, what can I do?

Comment: Hi, It almost work. My problem is, that the script want to delete only one file, and that is not the file what I need to delete. Second problem is, there are 3 directories. There are 5 files in each directory, and there are one file in each directory what I need to delete. The script give me only one filename, but this file is wrong.
I changed the $sz variable to ":nopm:". So what do I wrong?
Do you have any idea.

Comment: I made another edit to my script. Give that a try.

Comment: I ran it, and it gave back all files that contains ":nopm:".

Comment: Sorry, I keep missing things. Altered the script once more. Give that a try.

Comment: Hey man. You are brilliant. It works perfectly. Than you so much. I appriciate your quick response. Thanks again. Best. Regars: Richard